# How do I access methods of a class inside of an array

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have a custom class that holds information about a car like the stock number, vin and so on. I used properties as a getter and setter to set all the information. I then make an instance of this class and store it in an NSMutableArray. So now I have an array that contains all the different cars on our lot.

My question is how can I access the class members directly in the array:

```
Veh *veh = [[Veh alloc] init];
veh.Stock = @"P9494";
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:veh];
// here is what I want to do, access Stock directly from the array
NSString* string = [[array objectAtIndex:0].Stock];
```

Comment: Notes: 1. this is not an Xcode question, 2. property, instance variable and method names begin with lowercase letters by convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example has an extra dot or pair of brackets. To fix it, you can either remove the dot and call the method `Stock` on your object:

```
NSString* string = [[array objectAtIndex:0] Stock] ;
```

Or you can remove the brackets and tell Xcode that your object is a `Veh*`, allowing you to use the property `Stock`.

```
NSString* string = ((Veh*)[array objectAtIndex:0]).Stock ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps by using the correct syntax?

```
NSString *string = [[array objectAtIndex:0] Stock];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
NSString* string = ((Veh *)[[array objectAtIndex:0]).Stock];
```

Comment: `[[array objectAtIndex:0].Stock]` is wrong. That is the mistake OP has made in question as well. Either you should use `[[array objectAtIndex:0] Stock]` or `[array objectAtIndex:0].Stock`. Your above line wont execute at all. Check the other two answers.